# Tags in HTML Parsing

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup

I am writing a parsing script using BeautifulSoup in which I search through all `img` tags in a page and only want to grab pictures with a certain width.

Here's an example of a tag:

```
<img 
  alt="" 
  src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/111px-Example.jpg"
  width="111"
  height="120"
/>
```

The problem is that not all `img` tags have a `width` attribute. I would like to only access the `img` tags that have the `width` attribute.

So far I have something along the lines of:

```
images= soup.findAll("img")
listimages= []
for img in images:
    if img['width']!==None:
       listimages.append(img)
```

This does not seem to work. It seems that the lack of `width` attribute does not yield a `NoneType`. So if not `None`, then what?

Comment: If you run into a similar problem in the future that cannot be solved by a list comprehension try `img.get('width')`. It will return None as you expect if there is no such attr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[img for img in soup.findAll("img") if "width" in img.attrs]
```

Comment: Some additional context might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup provides a way of calling [`findAll()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) to handle this:

```
soup.findAll("img", width=True)
```

From the link above:

> The special values True and None are of special interest. True matches a tag that has any value for the given attribute, and None matches a tag that has no value for the given attribute. Some examples:
>
> ```
> soup.findAll(align=True)
> # [<p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>,
> #  <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>]
>
> [tag.name for tag in soup.findAll(align=None)]
> # [u'html', u'head', u'title', u'body', u'b', u'b']
> ```